# How to pass selected tree object from one page to another

Tags: wpf

I have a treeview like in below:
[image]

And when I click parent node(Name:Patience_name_1) I want to get that object with sub items, and send it to other page (EditPatient).

I don't want to use query string for this purpose I want to send them as a class instance how can I accomplish this ?

**EDITED:**

Here is the cs file of .xaml and Patient class:

```
 public partial class PatientTree : Page
    {
        public PatientTree()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillTree(trvMenu);
        }

        public patients fillTree(TreeView treeView)
        {
            DataReader readXML = new DataReader();
            patients patients = new patients();

            patients.patients_list = readXML.ReadXML();

            foreach (patient item in patients.patients_list)
            {
                TreeViewItem _patientNode = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = String.Format("Name:{0}", item.name),
                    IsExpanded = true
                };

                _patientNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = String.Format("Name:{0}", item.name),
                    IsExpanded = true,
                });
                _patientNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = String.Format("Surname:{0}", item.surname),
                    IsExpanded = true,
                });
                _patientNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = String.Format("Gender:{0}", item.gender),
                    IsExpanded = true,
                });
                foreach (exam exam in item.exam)
                {
                    TreeViewItem _exam = new TreeViewItem
                    {
                        Header = "Exams",
                        IsExpanded = true
                    };
                    _exam.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                    {
                        Header = String.Format("Id:{0}", exam.id),
                    });
                    _exam.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                    {
                        Header = String.Format("Comment:{0}", exam.comment),
                    });
                    _exam.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                    {
                        Header = String.Format("Date:{0}", exam.DateString),
                    });
                    _patientNode.Items.Add(_exam);
                }
                treeView.Items.Add(_patientNode);
            }

            return patients;
        }

        private void trvMenu_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = trvMenu.SelectedItem;
            EditPatient patient = new EditPatient();
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(patient);
        }

    }
```

patient class:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("patients")]
    public class patients
    {
        [XmlElement("patient")]
        public List<patient> patients_list { get; set; }

    }
    public class patient
    {
        [XmlElement("firstname")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastname")]
        public string surname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("age")]
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("exams"), XmlArrayItem("exam")]
        public List<exam> exam { get; set; }
    }
    public class exam
    {
        [XmlElement("id", IsNullable = false)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string DateString
        {
            get
            {
                return XmlConvert.ToString(date, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
            }
            set
            {
                date = DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
            }
        }
        [XmlElement("comment")]
        public string comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How is your TreeView's items collection set up? Is it bound to a collection of patients? A little more information on this might be helpful.

Comment: @Rowbear Hello, I have edited post with details of items collected and class declaration

Comment: You should't construct the tree from code behind like that, that's your problem. Check articles for [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn how to bind the tree correctly. Then you'll have your selected object just by using `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: @icebat but I read datas from an xml documents.. is there a way bind treei do xml document directly ?